# div.modal-backdrop places itself within the modal. No addtional code

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue with the modal-backdrop div that the js creates. It keeps placing the div with in the modal. I have no additional code added yet but I am using jQuery 2.1.3. I am literally just copying the modal into my html.

Comment: Create a fiddle or [bootply](http://bootply.com) with your code to demonstrate the issue

Answer (score 0):

Compiler referred to another instance of Jquery that bootstrap found incompatible.